# Series sequences

Tags: real-analysis

A have a series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$
I would like to know if it is possible to find a large finite integer n such that:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}<\epsilon$, $\displaystyle \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Comment: Please, do not change your question in such a way *after* an answer has been posted.

Comment: It is just the definition of "convergence" for a series, and yes, $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$$ is convergent, for instance by comparison with a telescopic series. Its exact value is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio look at the quantifiers, the "natural" parsing of the sentence makes them wrong for the definition of convergence you mention.

Comment: @ClementC.: you are right, but I also think the original question had the quantifiers in the most natural order $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: \sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}<\varepsilon.$$ Otherwise, the question is really trivial.

Comment: The original question had no epsilon, so it's unclear to me what the OP originally intended (that's why my answer covers all 3 variants).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No (for the original question, with equality to zero): $\exists n, \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = 0$.**

You are summing non-negative terms. Having the sum equal to $0$ would imply every single term is zero. But every term is positive.

With more symbols (but the same argument): assume by contradiction such a $n\geq 1$ exists. Then
$$
0 = \frac{1}{(2n-1^2} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \underbrace{\frac{1}{(2k-1^2}}_{\geq 0}
\geq  \frac{1}{(2n-1^2} > 0
$$
leading to a contradiction.

---

**No, for the new question with the quantifiers: $\exists n, \forall \varepsilon > 0,\ \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} < \varepsilon$.**

Indeed, this is then the same question as before, as this implies equality to $0$ (just take the limits on both sides as $\varepsilon \to 0$).

---

**Yes, for the different question inverting the quantifiers: $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists n,\ \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} < \varepsilon$.**

Your series converges, so the remainder tends to zero by definition. That is, as in addition the terms of the series are all non-negative,
$$
0 \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
which will give you what you want (by recalling the definition of a limit).

Comment: Clement C. see my edit

Comment: So, you basically entirely changed the question after the answer? That's not good practice.

Comment: Oh i'm Sorry!!!

Comment: You don't need the contradiction argument. The last two inequalities alone give you the direct proof.

Comment: @IsraelMeirelesChrisostomo I have edited my anser -- see above.

Comment: It is in fact the same question: if a non-negative number is less than $\;\epsilon\;$ , **for all** $\;\epsilon >0\;$ , then it **must** be zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, see what I wrote.

Comment: Excellent answer to *several* questions... +1